# custom function to be used with recent posts of 2 categories

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops

I know this may be simple, but I'm still a little new to WP and PHP and can't figure this one out.

Originally, the page was pulling recent posts from 1 category into a group of various columns.  That was done nicely with a custom function:

```
category_loop('columns', 'Recent Articles', 4);

function category_loop($id, $name, $number)
```

The category id was columns, title of section was recent post and it had 4 total posts.

Well, now they need it to be pulled form 2 categories - "columns" and "commentary" and, without rewriting all of the current code, I was wondering if there was a way to do something  with an array (or anything) to allow for the 2 category $ids to be used in the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can provide more code if necessary.

Thanks so much!

EDIT:  Here is the function itself:

```
}
function category_loop($id, $name, $number){
    $weather = get_category_by_slug('the-weather');
$acupuncture = get_category_by_slug('acupuncture-after-the-apocalypse');
$letters = get_category_by_slug('letters-from-the-editors');
?>

<div class="category-block">
    <div class="category-block-title">
        <div style="margin-top: 4px;">
          <?php echo $name ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="<?php echo $id ?>-posts" class="category-post-loop">

<?php
 remove_action('genesis_post_content', 'genesis_do_post_content');
 add_action('genesis_post_content', 'do_post_excerpt');

 add_filter('genesis_post_title', 'trop_byline_short');

// Columns -- be sure to remove featured posts
$args = array( 'category_name' => $id, 'cat' => '-'.$weather->cat_ID.',-'
.$acupuncture->cat_ID.',-'.$letters->cat_ID, 'orderby' => 'date', 
'posts_per_page' => $number, 'meta_query' => array(array( 'key' => 'featured', 
'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS' )) );
genesis_custom_loop( $args );

remove_filter('genesis_post_title', 'trop_byline_short');

add_action('genesis_post_content', 'genesis_do_post_content');
remove_action('genesis_post_content', 'do_post_excerpt');

?>
```

Comment: Where is it pulling the data from? Is it a database with SQL or something else?

Comment: Can we see the contents of the function itself? `{ ?? }`

Comment: It's pulling the data from a MySQL Database (wordpress).  @Wezly, I added the function to my post.

Comment: *opens can of worms* ..Looks like we might also need to see the `genesis_custom_loop()` function, who wrote this!?

Comment: @Wezly it's a child theme for the genesis framework.  Genesis is crazy when it comes to removing and adding actions.  I have to dig to find that loop cause it's in the main genesis theme folder.

Comment: Ah, okay - Perhaps you should tag your question with 'genesis' and ask more specifically how to work with this framework.. Have you tried simply passing two categories, comma separated, to the function like this `category_loop('columns, commentary', 'Recent Articles', 4);`

Comment: HA!  Oh, boy do I feel dumb.  I tried that a few times yesterday, but put 'columns','commentary' instead of leaving out the '.  That works.